# x-systemd.automount does not work for ext4 on LVM LV

Tags: 14.04, server, mount, automount

For following setup:

```
$ lvcreate -L 2048G -n lv99 vg99
$ mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/vg99-lv99
$ blkid /dev/mapper/vg99-lv99
/dev/mapper/vg99-lv99: UUID="11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555" TYPE="ext4"
```

automounting via `x-systemd.automount` option (I followed [those snippets](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab#Automount_with_systemd)) , fails:

```
$ tail -n 1 /etc/fstab
UUID=11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555 /mnt/m99 ext4 defaults,rw,relatime,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=60min 0 2
$ ls -l /mnt/m99
total 0
$ mount | grep m99
$ mount /mnt/m99
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vgnaszrh2016-lvzrhnas2016ext4,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Even for simplified options:

```
$ tail -n 1 /etc/fstab
UUID=11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555 /mnt/m99 ext4 defaults,rw,relatime,noauto,x-systemd.automount 0 2
```

It only works without `x-systemd.automount` :

```
$ tail -n 1 /etc/fstab
UUID=11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555 /mnt/m99 ext4 defaults,rw,relatime,noauto 0 2
```

Above happens on Ubuntu Server LTS 14.04

Answer (score 1):

I guess (I make this answer "community wiki" so feel free to improve), that is because Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS does not use (by default) systemd, so it does not know about x-systemd.automount concept.